# How to add a common observer in rxjava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I am pretty new to rxjava and just started learning it and converting our android project to rx.
So I wrote observables and chained them using flatmaps to call apis and return an observable. Now in the main activity I subscribe to them and add my UI code to onNext, onSubscribe, onComplete and onError as applicable.
But I have mutiple apis for which I have created an observable for each api, but I want to have a wrapper over the observer with which I subscribe to them. It is mainly to execute a piece of code like logging onNext/onError calls and showing a progress status on onSubscribe and dismissing it on onComplete/onError etc.

How do I do this other than adding it each time or having a baseobserver and adding super.method each time (one may forget super.method hence this handling should be removed from activity code I guess)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to implement a `BaseActivity` where all other activities extends from it. In this activity, you declare your generic `Observer` and when extending from this class, you get that Observer and you can make your own modifications depending on your needs. Take a look at this [code](https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/Rx-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/fakher/rx/ui/fragments/BaseFragment.java)

Comment: But again, if I need to execute something else after show/hide progress bar, I need to override it and use super.onNext for those functions. I don't want to leave it to the activity to implement this. I needed to separate it from activity code. If I was working with listeners as in my earlier code without rx, I had a listener interface which after api call, called hideprogressbar, logs stuff and then call the listener.onSuccess/onError with the relevant data. I needed something on a similar design using rx

Comment: it's a bad concept that you control your UI from a Non UI classes (Activities or Fragments) you must always pass the context as parameter and cast it so you can call appropriete methods on your views. I advise you to control your UI componenet from either Activities or Fragments

Comment: Its sort of ui utils which I was thinking. Otherwise, I would need to call show/hide progress bar, etc (which are needed with almost all other calls) everytime with that line of code in each activity/fragment